# How do I quickly move a bunch of cards to a different list?

Tags: trello

I'm reviewing a *Done* list that has been allowed to sprawl. I'm moving cards to *Done (month)* lists. This means I have to: (1) open card, review date; (2) click on **Move**; (3) click on the list dropdown, navigate to the target list; (4) click **Move** in the modal; (5) close the card; (6) mouse to the next card.

This is pretty terrible.

- Drag'n'drop doesn't work, because I need to open the card first to review it.
- The `>` `<` shortcuts don't help much, because I need to close the card after moving and mouse back to open the next card.
- There's no keyboard shortcut to quickly move a card.

What would help:

- a way to move the card I'm viewing with `>` without leaving the current list. Notification says "card X was moved", my view changes to the next card in the origin list.
- a keyboard shortcut to move a card, with a widget that remembers where I last moved a card (then moving becomes `M<cr>M<cr>M` *choose new list* `<cr>M<cr>` ...)

Am I missing a good way to do this now?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding here, but when I am in my Trello board, whatever card my mouse is hovering over *or* clicked into is what moves when I press `>` or `<` and my card doesn't close.

I understand you need to not close the card, but I'm confused about what you need to happen after you move the card.

Also, are you needing to move these cards to lists within the same board, or different boards?

Comment: @xtoq after I move one card, I want to move to the next card *in the original list*. But after moving the card, `J` goes to the next card in the *new* list. I'm moving them to an adjacent list in the same board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Butler function. It is limited in the free version but it's very helpful. Set an automation rule, something like:

when a due date not in this month is set on a card by anyone, move the card to the next list on the board.

It's really easy, Trello provides spinner options for creating rules.